# Mypy fails with overloads and literals

Tags: python, overloading, mypy

I'm trying to understand `typing.overload` and have applied it in a simple case where I want a function that takes input `x: Literal["foo", "bar"]` and returns the list `[x]`.

I'd like mypy to type the resulting list as `list[Literal["foo"]]` or `list[Literal["bar"]]` depending on the value of `x`.

I know I could achieve this with a `TypeVar`, but I'd still like to understand why the code below fails with the following error:

```
test.py:14: error: Overloaded function implementation cannot produce return type of signature 1
test.py:14: error: Overloaded function implementation cannot produce return type of signature 2
```

```py
from typing import Literal, overload


@overload
def f(x: Literal["foo"]) -> list[Literal["foo"]]:
    ...


@overload
def f(x: Literal["bar"]) -> list[Literal["bar"]]:
    ...


def f(x: Literal["foo", "bar"]) -> list[Literal["foo", "bar"]]:
    return [x]
```

Comment: The correct return type hint for the base function should be `Union[List[Literal["foo"]], List[Literal["bar"]]]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lists in Python are invariant. That means that, even if `B` is a subtype of `A`, there is *no relation* between the types `list[A]` and `list[B]`.

If `list[B]` were allowed to be a subtype of `list[A]`, then someone could come along and do this.

```
my_b_list: list[B] = []
my_a_list: list[A] = my_b_list
my_a_list.append(A())
print(my_b_list) # Oh no, a list[B] contains an A value!
```

If you plan to modify the returned list, then what you're doing isn't safe. End of story. If you plan to treat the list as immutable, then consider what operations you *actually* need, and you may be able to find a covariant supertype of `list` in [`typing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

For example, [`Sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Sequence) is a popular choice. It supports iteration, random access, and length access, while explicitly *not* allowing mutation.

```
from typing import Literal, overload, Sequence


@overload
def f(x: Literal["foo"]) -> Sequence[Literal["foo"]]:
    ...


@overload
def f(x: Literal["bar"]) -> Sequence[Literal["bar"]]:
    ...


def f(x: Literal["foo", "bar"]) -> Sequence[Literal["foo", "bar"]]:
    return [x]
```

(Note: `typing.Sequence` is deprecated in Python 3.9; if you only plan to support 3.9+, you might use `collections.abc.Sequence` instead)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIU your question, your actual implementation needs to provide a single type (`str`), not multiple `Literal`.

The following works correctly according to `pyright`, and seems to provide the feature you are looking for (only allowing lists of either `"foo"` or `"bar"`, rejecting everything else).

```
from typing import Literal, overload


@overload
def f(x: Literal["foo"]) -> list[Literal["foo"]]:
    ...


@overload
def f(x: Literal["bar"]) -> list[Literal["bar"]]:
    ...


def f(x: str) -> list[str]:
    return [x]


f("foo")  # valid
f("bar")  # valid
f("baz")  # error
```

which cause the following error:

```
a.py:20:3 - error: Argument of type "Literal['baz']" cannot be assigned to parameter "x" of type "Literal['bar']" in function "f"
    "Literal['baz']" cannot be assigned to type "Literal['bar']"
```

Comment: I still get `error: Overloaded function implementation cannot produce return type of signature 1/2` with mypy - and, additionally, `No overload variant of "f" matches argument type "str"`

Comment: Interesting. This may be one of the cases where mypy produces incorrect results. I used to use mypy myself, got frustrated, and switched to pyright, which provides the same and more features, but stays a lot closer to the specs of Python.